# Pinia and Nuxt3 Server routes: Data is undefined when accessing from local component

Tags: firebase, nuxtjs3, pinia

I am using Pinia to fetch and store blog comments from Firebase Firestore.

**I can not figure out why the `comments` array is `undefined` when fetching from Firestore when using the server route api in Nuxt 3 (see below code).**

Yet, I do see data coming in when console logging the fetch request from Pinia

`/stores/comments.ts`:

```js
import {defineStore} from 'pinia'

export const useComment = defineStore('comment', {

    state: () => {
        return {
            comments: []
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchComments(routeParamsId: String) {
            console.log(1, routeParamsId)
            const {data} = await useFetch(`/api/comments/${routeParamsId}`)
            console.log(2, data)
            this.comments = data
        }
    }
})
```

The `comments.vue` component:

```js
<script setup>
import { useComment } from '@/stores/comment'
const route = useRoute()
const commentStore = useComment()
const comments = await commentStore.fetchComments(route.params.id)
console.log(3, comments) // <---- console log says: 3, undefined
</script>
```

Console.log 3 shows: `3, undefined`

```
1 sdfgsdfgsdfg_wsCb
2 RefImpl {
  __v_isShallow: false,
  dep: undefined,
  __v_isRef: true,
  _rawValue: [
    {
      comment: 'test comment',
      displayName: 'John Doe',
      likes: 0,
      uid: 'TIkHA7B3akn28biaGU5sJ0riZp2',
      createdAt: [Object],
      postId: 'sdfgsdfgsdfg_wsCb',
      commentId: 'mHRoyGlfJrZNSnPBEo7m',
      parentCommentId: null
    }
  ],
  _value: [
    {
      comment: 'test comment',
      displayName: 'John Doe,
      likes: 0,
      uid: 'TIkHA7B3akn28biaGU5sJ0riZp2',
      createdAt: [Object],
      postId: 'sdfgsdfgsdfg_wsCb',
      commentId: 'mHRoyGlfJrZNSnPBEo7m',
      parentCommentId: null
    }
  ]
}
```

`server/api/comments/[postId].ts`:

```js
import { firestore } from '@/server/utils/firebase'

export default defineEventHandler(async (event) => {
    // console.log(2, event.context.params.postId)
    const commentsRef = firestore.collection('comments')
    const snapshot = await commentsRef.where('postId', '==', event.context.params.postId).get()
    const comments = []
    if (snapshot.empty) {
        console.log('No matching documents.')
        return
      }

      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        comments.push(doc.data())
      })
        return comments
})
```

Should I be setting up the fetch differently somewhere in `comments.vue` file?

Answer (score 1):

So a couple of issues here that I have fixed which solves my question:

First, it's recommended to use `$fetch` method when fetching data in Pinia store:
https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/2940#discussioncomment-2052627

(it also works better when troubleshooting Pinia data fetching within Vue Devtools)

Second, the mistake I made was that I was doing:
`const comments = await commentStore.fetchComments(route.params.id)`
and I needed to call the comments array from the store directly, rather than using the action. Thus, I had updated my `Comments.vue` code like so:

```js
<template>
<AppSpinner v-if="loading" />
        <CommentsList :comments="commentStore.comments" v-else />
</template>

<script setup>
import { useComment } from '@/stores/comment'

const route = useRoute()

const commentStore = useComment()

const loading = ref(false)

loading.value = true
await commentStore.fetchComments(route.params.id)
loading.value = false
</script>
```